# Is it possible to statistically test relationships between counts and percentages?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, proportion, count-data, percentage

I have counted adult butterfly numbers over 3 areas and would like to compare these counts with the percentage heather cover on each of the 3 areas. Is this possible?

My data looks like this (the cover is the average for each area whilst count is the total number of adults observed over 10 days – let me know if this should be an average instead):

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}\rm Area&\rm Cover&\rm Count\\\hline
\rm Field\ 1&    53.7& 216\\
\rm Field\ 2&19.5& 2\\
\rm Field\ 3&39.8& 6106\end{array}$$

I suspect from looking at these figures that there probably won't be a relationship, but I would still like to test the relationship nonetheless.

I know that there are specific statistical tests for proportion data and other tests for count data because of the way both count and percentage data behave, but I wonder if there is one that will analyse both? I am using the R software environment.

Comment: When you say 'compare' can you be more specific about the question you're trying to address?

Comment: So I'm trying to see if there is a relationship between percentage heather cover and adult butterfly abundance. The above figures for cover refer to total heather cover but I will also look separately at whether adult abundance varies as a function of the cover of bell heather and ling heather. Hope that helps.

Comment: "compare A and B" isn't really the same as "see if there's a relationship between A and B". It sounds like you need something like regression, whereas your title suggests something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to do a Poisson regression (`glm` function in R) with the count as the response variable and the percent cover as the predictor.  Linear models don't care much about whether the predictor is a percentage, count, continuous, etc.  You could also do a logit transform on the percentage cover if that is the scale that makes more sense to you.

Comment: And consider `glm.nb` (negative binomial regression) from the `MASS` package if the counts are overdispersed, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I was going to do a glm poisson regression and this puts my mind at ease! Also Nick, I have been taught that if the data is overdispersed then creating a model from the quasipoisson family is one method. Does this sound right?

Comment: I hadn't heard of that option before, so I'm not sure how it compares to NB regression. You may be interested in this article: [Quasi-Poisson vs. negative binomial regression: how should we model overdispersed count data?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18051645)